# d3.js sub-select a bar from a bar chart

Tags: d3.js, selection, bar-chart

I have a bar chart in d3.js and would like to change the color of just one bar when a function is called. I have a function and when I call this the whole bar chart changes the color. This is what is written in the function:

```
d3.selectAll(".barD").style("fill", "orange");
```

This changes the color of all bars which is quite logical as all the bars are assigned the "barD" class. But how can I change only the color of one bar. Can I sub-select one bar based on its e.g. name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to filter your selection instead of subselecting explicitly:

```
d3.selectAll(".barD")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name == "someName"; })
  .style("fill", "orange");
```

You could also match the data for the bar in question to the selection and filter that way:

```
d3.selectAll(".barD")
  .data([datumForBar], function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill", "orange");
```

If you're calling said function from the event handler of one of the bars (e.g. click), remember that the current element is also available in the `this` variable and you could simply do

```
d3.select(this).style("fill", "orange");
```

Comment: The first version worked fine for me! Thank you! Just one more question: when I say `.filter(function(d) { return d.name == "someName"; })` where "someName" is a name, it somehow doesn't work. But if I use d.value which relates to a number, it works? For me, it doesn't matter what I use for the filter but I'm wondering why it isn't working with a name?

Comment: Can't really say without seeing your code and data. Have you used the right attribute name?

Comment: yes I did! Could it be because the name contains space characters?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Could you post the exact code please?